# PHP API: Same code in two environments, on same server, different speeds

Tags: php

Hope the title wasn't too confusing.

I have a TEST and PROD environment running the exact same PHP API code. Both "environments" run on the same VM.

Access to PROD is made through live.myapi.com and TEST is made through test.myapi.com. Both domains point to the same IP and all requests for both are made through SSL. (doubt any of that matters but there it is anyway)

If I run a test on the search end point in both I get HUGE differences in execution times.

PROD https://live.myapi.com/search 1.5s to 5.8s
TEST https://test.myapi.com/search 0.07s to 0.2s

PROD is more than 10x slower than TEST even though they're the same code and running on the same VM.

The API contacts a remote database in AWS (Aurora) and the absolute only difference between these two APIs is they communicate with a PROD and TEST database respectively. The databases are running on the same server as well so there's no difference in hardware between them either.

I changed the search object in PROD to point to the TEST database but still got the same times.

Then I changed the search object in TEST to point to the PROD database and it was still super fast.

I also made sure they were getting the same record returned in the search for both environments but changed the value of one column for TEST so it would be clear the changes I made were actually taking effect. They definitely were.

So I think I've eliminated the database as the issue but I cannot think of anything else that would be causing these ridiculous speed differences.

I'm hoping that maybe some of you have some ideas for what else I can look for to determine why PROD would be running so slow.

Thanks in advance for any help and for reading this.

Comment: I think you should try to profile your code. Split your script with a bunch of checkpoints, and measure the time interval between adjacent checkpoints, so you may be able to see where the issue is located

Comment: have you speed tested each step to find were the issue is?

Comment: Just for fun, are the DB tables indexed in a way that will help the query? Do the DBs have similar sizes? (I realize you said you pointed TEST at prod data but, it always pays to be sure)

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I'll add checkpoints in the search object and report back, may take a while. As for the DB tables, they're all indexed the same and appropriately (not searching on any unindexed fields) and their sizes are similar (off by maybe a few k here and there). The biggest difference was an api execution time log table which was huge in PROD but I truncated that first thing and it had no impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the difference was database related.

One of the nested classes in my search API was calling a function to age off old access logs.

In TEST this took no time because it doesn't get a lot of traffic. But in PROD it took much longer and varied depending on the traffic (we have a bunch of sites that use this same API so LOTS of traffic).

I removed the aging function call from the search stack and made it a separate end point then wired that up to cron.

I underestimated how much traffic the sites get when coding that before.

Thanks all for the helpful advice!